# enable button if only 1 checkbox is checked..else disable the button

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {



title = "Angular 2 - enable button based on checkboxes";
  checkboxes = [{label: 'one',selected:false},


  {label: 'two',selected:false}

  ];
selectedFileList:any[]=[];
checkClicked(event: Event, i) {
    if (event.target['checked']) {

      this.selectedFileList.push(i);

      console.log("selected checkBox is: "+this.selectedFileList);

    }
    else {
      let index = this.selectedFileList.indexOf(i);
      if (index !== -1) this.selectedFileList.splice(index, 1);
      console.log("inside else")
      this.selectedFileList=[];

    }
   }


  constructor() { console.clear(); }
  buttonState() {
    // console.log('buttonState() called');
    return !this.checkboxes.some(cb => cb.selected) && (this.selectedFileList.length=1);
  }
  get debug() {
    return JSON.stringify(this.checkboxes);
  }

}
```

I am checking the length of selectedFileList to check if more than 1 cb is selected but unable to do so please help.

button should be enabled only if 1 cb is selected and disabled if 0 or more than 1 selected

stackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjccyp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: It seems like you should be using a radio button

Comment: @Explosion Pills no functionality does not allow that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
!this.checkboxes.some(cb => cb.selected)
```

to

```
this.checkboxes.filter(cb => cb.selected).length === 1
```

also you assign (not check) `1` in `this.selectedFileList.length=1`